# Lambda that creates ELB WAF Rule

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-elb, amazon-waf

I am pretty new to AWS, sorry for dump question. 
I have found Documentation about [Create WAF Rule API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/APIReference/API_CreateRule.html)

**Request Syntax:**

```
{
   "ChangeToken": "string",
   "MetricName": "string",
   "Name": "string"
}
```

1. I assume above is the request body. What is the request endpoint?
2. How the Lambda code should look like when calling WAF Rule API?

Comment: Kudos on reading the reference documentation, but you are asking how to do this the hard way, calling the service API directly -- viable, but usually unnecessary. More is involved than just passing a valid request body to the right endpoint.  There are already official libraries available to do this all for you, and handle sigining (for authentication) of the request as well... but of course this depends on which language you're using to write the Lambda function.  Which language are you using?

Comment: I am using golang

Comment: Take a look at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/waf/.